# docker-compose environment will cover variables in jar, how are docker environment variable and variable in jar mapped?

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-compose

For example, set `environment: EUREKA_PORT=8762` in docker-compose.yml.

And the variable `${eureka.port=8761}` in jar will not effective.

---

Why `environment: EUREKA_PORT=8762` will cover `${eureka.port=8761}`?

How are **docker environment variable** and **variable in jar** mapped?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are dumping the value for `{$eureka.port}` in your java code to say that it is `8761` value. `{$eureka.port}` looks shell` to me. Anyway I don't think `EUREKA_PORT` is the same as `eureka.port`. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are exactly right with your way of thinking - `EUREKA_PORT=8762` will set `eureka.port` through the environment. It's the way it works:

> If you use environment variables rather than system properties, most operating systems disallow **period-separated** key names, but you can use **underscores** instead (e.g. `SPRING_CONFIG_NAME` instead of `spring.config.name`).

Taken straight from [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).